# В чем причина ошибки при использовании VBO?

Tags: opengl, исключения

Вылетает на строке:

```
glGenBuffersARB(1, &vertexArrayVBO);
```

Пишет:

> Необработанное исключение в "0x00000000" в "n-bodies.exe": 0xC0000005: Access violation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас наверняка указатель на функицю glGenBuffersARB = 0, вот и случается ошибка вызова функции по адресу 0. Проверьте код, который ищет адрес функции.

**UPD** Ну и разумеется, glGenBuffersARB = 0 в случае, если расширение ARB_vertex_buffer_object не поддерживается.

Comment: Выше прописано след. :
    PFNGLGENBUFFERSARBPROC glGenBuffersARB = NULL;
PFNGLBINDBUFFERARBPROC glBindBufferARB = NULL;
PFNGLBUFFERDATAARBPROC glBufferDataARB = NULL;        
PFNGLDELETEBUFFERSARBPROC glDeleteBuffersARB = NULL;
Но ведь без этого линковщик пожалуется на неразреш.символ?

Comment: С какой стати? У вас ведь указатель на функцию. Его и надо выставлять либо вручную, либо использовать какие-то уже готовые либы для их поиска. Либо использовать GLEW.

Comment: такс, пойдем сначала.
файл glew.h подключен, .lib тоже на месте
теперь до вызова функции
    glGenBuffersARB() что нибудь надо писать?

Comment: Хоть догадку-то проверьте. Я GLEW никогда не использовал, так что не могу быть уверен..

Comment: Ошибка остается. Вы не знаете, что вообще должно быть подключено, чтобы работать с VBO?

Comment: Так равен указатель на функцию нулю или нет?